# Using VB.NET to add formula to excel spread sheet considering unknown columns

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-formula, export

I am using VB.NET to create an excel file. This excel file are multiple other excel files being compiled into a single file. I need to add a formula to the bottom but because I don't know how many columns there will be, because the amount of excel files vary, I don't know what my intended range will be. I need to use a formula to take an average of the previous 8 entries and I need to know how many total columns the excel sheet is using. I tried using the complete row style range set but it did not work.
Here is what I was trying:

```
 xlworksheet.range("I53:53").formula = ("AVERAGE(B45:I45)")
```

So in short this would write the average from cells B45 to I45 into cell I53, then the next iteration would be the average of cells C45 to J45 into cell J53.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
xlworksheet.range("I53").Formula = "=AVERAGE(B45:I45)"
xlworksheet.range("J53").Formula = "=AVERAGE(C45:J45)"
etc.
```

Comment: @ Did this answer your question?